# Difference between header files and interfaces

Tags: java, c++, c, interfaces

I wanted to know whether the header files in c and c++ have same function as that of interfaces used in Java? If not what is the difference between header file and interface?

Answer (score 7):

Not quite. Definitions in a header file correspond more closely to `public` members of a Java class. Both header files and public/private access modifiers allow us to make a distinction between the publicly visible interface/API of our code, and its internal implementation details.

C or C++ declarations are subject to the One Definition Rule. A compiled program can contain only one implementation for each declared function or global variable (unless it is declared as `inline`, in which all definitions MUST be equivalent). So for one function declaration in a header, I write one function definition in a .c or .cpp file. If I want to use a different definition, I need to recompile the code.

Java `interface`s (or C++ classes with pure virtual methods) also declare a kind of “interface”, but it is very different: one `class` can implement many `interface`s, and one `interface` can be implemented by many `class`es. The latter point is very important: I can write code that only calls methods on an object through an `interface`. Later, I can provide objects that conform to this `interface` to that code, and the code will still work! I can choose multiple implementations at run time, without having to recompile the code. This provides a lot of flexibility, e.g. for dependency injection.

Fundamentally, headers and `interface`s work very differently. Headers contain forward declarations that are resolved later, but still during compilation. An `interface` (or non-`final` `class`) defines virtual methods that are resolved at run time through *dynamic dispatch*.

They also mean different concepts. Mechanisms like headers and public/private access modifiers in classes allow us to implement *abstract data types* (ADTs). ADTs encapsulate implementation details of some data structure, and only allow external code to access to those structures through public functions or methods. In contrast, `interface`s and virtual methods allow us to implement *objects*. One `interface` can be implemented by many different objects. This ability of objects of one common `interface` to behave differently is also called *polymorphism*.

ADTs and objects both have something to do with “encapsulation”, but they do that very differently. They should be understood as *complementary concepts*.

However, there has been significant interest in object-oriented solutions. E.g. the *Design Patterns* book investigates how applying object-oriented techniques like dynamic dispatch can introduce enough flexibility into a software system to solve some interesting problems. As a random example, the *Composite Pattern* allows us to treat collections of items equivalently to a single item. How? both the collection and single items implement the same `interface`. This wouldn't be possible just with header files.

Comment: BTW, you might want to point to William Cook's *On Understanding Data Abstraction, Revisited*, which explains the difference between Abstract Data Types and Objects.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I'm actually in the middle of reading that paper! Which, I think, shows in the answer :)